# DLL Export and virtual methods

Tags: visual-c++, abstract-class, dllexport

In a Windows project we define an interface class

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual ~Interface() { }
    virtual void func() = 0;
};
```

and a factory function

```
__declspec(dllexport) Interface *construct();
```

inside a DLL. Of course there is a concrete specialization of `Interface` inside the DLL but we don't export it. Nevertheless we can use it outside the DLL. How does this work? The `vftable` of the instance constructed by `construct()` consists of function pointers targeting functions which aren't exported by the DLL. Is this approach acceptable or more or less a hack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There just isn't any need to export the concrete class.  The v-table you get from the Interface pointer will be set to the concrete v-table stored inside the DLL.  Which already has all the function pointers set correctly to the implementation methods.  So once you got the v-table pointer then you're golden and can call any of the concrete methods.  Compare with COM, you never export anything from a COM server, other than the factory function (DllGetClassObject).

You *do* have to export the construct() function, there isn't any other way that external code can obtain the address of this function.  A lookup table is required that maps the function name to the function address.  The export table of the DLL.  Exporting functions and classes add entries to that export table.

Comment: So if COM never export anything except the factory function too it must be an largely accepted technique.

Comment: And the layout of the v-table comes from the publicly available header which defines the `Interface`?

Comment: Yes, roughly, it is the compiler that builds it based on the declaration of the interface.  A rather infamous source of DLL Hell btw, versioning is difficult.  A client that uses a newer declaration of the interface and accidentally loads an old version of the DLL is going to crash badly.  The core reason that COM requires you to always change the interface IID when you change it.